# Show Mobile App dowload layer only in Mobiles and Tablets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

We have both website and Native App (iOS & Android) for my company.

**Requirement**

I would like to show Modal dialog layer particularly to Mobiles and tablets when user access site in devices and show message that you can download our native app

**Problem**

The HTML,CSS & javaScript code for these layer is impacting our page weight, is there any way we can include specific code (HTML, CSS & javaScript) dynamically only on Mobile & Tablet devices.

Thanks

Avinash Mudunuri

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something called a `userAgent`. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> identifies your browser and provides certain system details to servers hosting the websites you visit.

A typical useragent will look like this :

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0

For android phones, it will look something like this :

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

This property is accessible through the `navigator` object like this :

```
navigator.userAgent
```

See Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/cC7mY/

Now, to check if your browser is a mobile browser, we have set up a system like this :

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
if (ua.indexOf("Android") >= 0) {
     //its an android phone
     var androidversion = parseFloat(ua.slice(ua.indexOf("Android") + 8));
     if (androidversion != 4.0) {
        //version of android
     }
} else if ((ua.indexOf("iPhone") >= 0 || ua.indexOf("iPad") >= 0) && ua.indexOf("CriOS") == -1) {
    //you're on iOS
}
```

You'll have to put this at the start of your document before you load anything else in your page if you want to stop everything from loading.

**NOTE**
`CriOS` is the useragent indicator of Chrome browser on Safari. That's why its included in the iOS list.